# Find pixel height with Jquery?

Tags: jquery, html

I'm trying to test the pixel height using [this script](http://jsfiddle.net/MichaelT/Jqr6z/)

I'm basically trying to test when I want something to fade.

I've seen it before somewhere, on scroll I should be seeing numbers.

Answer (score 1):

There is an erroneous `})` in your code and you should load the jQuery from the left panel on jsfiddle:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(window).scroll(function(){
      $('#test').text($(this).scrollTop());
    });
 // }); this line should be removed
});
```

However the text is not visible when page is scrolled, you can make an element, style it's position as `fixed` and update it's text.

http://jsfiddle.net/Jqr6z/10/

Answer (score 1):

I fixed the code for you.

http://jsfiddle.net/Jqr6z/8/

Two things.

First there was an extra `});`

Second you had not included jquery.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this fiddle is what you need http://jsfiddle.net/Jqr6z/12/

```
$(window).scroll(function(){    
  $('#test').html($(this).scrollTop());
});
```